# How do i upload non english character to DDB using aws cli?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I am getting below error while updating data to DDB using aws cli

```
Error parsing parameter '--request-items': Unable to load paramfile (xxx.json), text contents could not be decoded.  If this is a binary file, please use the fileb:// prefix instead of the file:// prefix.
```

Here is my json

```
{
    "book": [
        {
            "PutRequest": {
                "Item": {
                    "id": {
                        "S": "1"
                    },
                    "test": {
                        "S": "本の説明は、裏表紙と Amazon ページの上部 (価格の下、本のレビューの上) に最も目立つように表示されます。読者は本の説明から購入を決定するため、説得力があることが重要です。"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You've confirmed that the request works when `"test"` does not contain non-english characters? 
DDB has some naming rules [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.NamingRulesDataTypes.html) you might want to look into

Comment: @WesleyCheekYes, I can confirm this request works with english content

Comment: Hmm that is odd that it works with English characters. [This issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/2370) seems similar and it turned out to be a JSON formatting issue. See my answer

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you might have improperly formatted `JSON`. Try this instead:

```json
{
    "book": [
        {
            "PutRequest": {
                "Item": {
                    "id": {
                        "S": "1"
                    },
                    "test": {
                        "S": "本の説明は、裏表紙と Amazon ページの上部 (価格の下、本のレビューの上) に最も目立つように表示されます。読者は本の説明から購入を決定するため、説得力があることが重要です。"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```